# Swift 3: index out of range error

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm new to iOS. Doing project by watching tutorial which is written using Swift 2.
 It works when author runs app but not in my case.

ViewController:

```
var books = [[String: AnyObject]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
}
```

And the extension

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookCell", for: indexPath)

        // error on this line
        if let volumeInfo = self.books[indexPath.row]["volumeInfo"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = volumeInfo["title"] as? String
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = volumeInfo["subtitle"] as? String
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

The console output:

[image]

Please, help me to identify what is the cause.

Comment: Doubt it has anything to do with Swift 3 vs 2. Your `books` array is probably empty (or at least `indexPath.section >= books.count`). Check what's inside `indexPath` and `books`, and make sure you're not missing a part of the code where the `books` array is initialized.

Comment: What do you return in `numberOfRowsInSection`? The `books` array is obviously empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return `books.count` from `numberOfRowsInSection`, **never** "hard-code" that value if it's related to the data source array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return books.count
}
```

PS: In Swift 3 you should use `[String:Any]` rather than `[String:AnyObject]`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming a lot about your project but if you only have one section in your tableView, which is the default, you shouldn't use indexPath.section for your books dictionary. You should use indexPath.row as seen below

Change -

```
if let volumeInfo = self.books[indexPath.section]["volumeInfo"] as? [String: AnyObject]
```

To -

```
if let volumeInfo = self.books[indexPath.row]["volumeInfo"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
```

Comment: Oh, sorry :( It was one of the trials to solve the problem. Actually it is a .row. Sorry again

Comment: That still shouldn't crash though as they're must be at least as many rows as there are sections.

Comment: No worries! I'm fairly new myself so I know how frustrating it can be.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You gave me general understanding about sections and rows

Comment: At what point are you getting the error? When you run the app? Also do you ever add any objects inside your books dictionary?

Comment: It turned out to be the missing `books.count`. For some reason I missed that part of the code from tutorial